# How to redefine ws.send to capture data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

How would i redefine what ws.send is in Chrome to capture data being sent?

example:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://mystuff.com');
ws.send = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg); //should log 'test'
    //Also somehow send the data as it would normally
};
ws.send('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate the send function to a new one, and then overwrite the original function to add your logs.
You will have to do it each time you create a websocket instance.

This is how you can do it.

```
//First, create a clone prototype

Function.prototype.clone = function() {
    var that = this;
    var temp = function temporary() { return that.apply(this, arguments); };
    for(var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = this[key];
        }
    }
    return temp;
};

//Then, when you create your ws object, use the clone function to copy the "send". For example, you can name the new function "parentSend"

ws = new WebSocket('ws://mystuff.com');
ws.parentSend = ws.send.clone();

//Finally, recode a new send function, with the logs, and the call to parentsend()

ws.send = function(msg){
     console.log(msg);
     this.parentSend(msg);
};
```

This will send the log, and call the original function just after

Answer (score 0):

I did it a simpler way

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:80");
ws.oldSend = ws.send;
ws.send = function(data) {
    ws.oldSend(data);
    console.log('Captured data:', data);
};`
```

Now whenever we call ws.send, it calls our redefined ws.send which sends it as well as logs the information being sent.

```
ws.send('Important data!'); //will show: Captured data: Important data!
```